# What does this split line in Scala mean?

Tags: regex, scala

I have a problem with a certain Scala code, where I found this split line. Before I only used split lines like:

```
var newLine = line.split(",")
```

But what does this split mean?

```
var newLine2 = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

The line I need to split looks like this:

```
1966, "Green, Green Grass of Home", Tom Jones, 850000
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside from the declaration syntax `val name = expression`, this is not a Scala thing. The `split` method is defined on `java.lang.String`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The string inside split method defines a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
The group `(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). That means split on a comma, but only if the pattern `([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$` is following the comma.

```
([^\"]*     # a series of non double quote characters
    \"      # a double quote
    [^\"]*  # a series of non double quote characters
\")         # a double quote
*           # repeat that whole group 0 or more times
[^\"]*$     # a series of non double quote characters till the end of the string
```

that means it will only split on commas, when there is an equal amount of double quotes following the comma, so in other words, **split only if the comma is not inside double quotes**. (This will work as long there are only pairs of quotes in the string.)

Comment: thanks for your quick und helpful answer! :) now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is an regular expression ("RegEx"), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression for an explanation